# iOS static library depending on other static library

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, static-libraries, socketrocket

I have created a static iOS library using this [tutorial](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/).
The library itself depends on the `SocketRocket` library.

SocketRocket is included as `#import <SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h>`.

When I build the library, everything works fine.
However, if I integrate my library into my sample project, the following error is thrown.

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
>
> 'SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h' file not found

**How can the library build, but later fail to find the file in the sample project?**

**UPDATE**

The Library has its Header Search Path set to `"$(SRCROOT)/Vendor/SocketRocket/"`, the sample project has the Header Search Path set to `"$(SRCROOT)/Vendor/MyLibrary/"`. If I set it to `"$(SRCROOT)/Vendor/MyLibrary/**"` it finds `SRWebSocket.h` and builds successfully. However, this includes all the SocketRocket Headers into the sample project as well and I don't want that.

**UPDATE 2**

I narrowed it down to the following

- In the static library one .h file uses `#import <SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h>` to import SocketRocket.
- If I add the library to my sample project, the SRWebSocket.h file is not found.
- How can I make the sample project recognise this file?

Comment: hi, was wondering if you were able to fix this issue? I'm in the same situation but I'm trying to make it work so that ponydebugger will work as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889888/socketrocket-after-trying-to-install-socketrocket-so-that-i-can-make-ponydebugge

Answer (score 0):

Have you made user that "Step 9: Final setup of app project" where you set your header search paths is actually pointing to the location of the header files?

Comment: what do you mean includes all the headers?  This path setting is only used so your project knows where to search for other headers ... when your app is compiled only those classes that it is references will be bundled up ... unused files wont be included in your app.