# SocketRocket After trying to install socketrocket so that I can make PonyDebugger work, I'm getting 3 Apple Match-O linker errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, websocket, socketrocket

I'm getting the fllowing. It's my first time trying to install this and I have to since I need the Pony Debugger working.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_utf8_countTrailBytes", referenced from:
      _validate_dispatch_data_partial_string in libSocketRocket.a(SRWebSocket.o)
  "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
      _validate_dispatch_data_partial_string in libSocketRocket.a(SRWebSocket.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT: I added the SocketRocket.Framework to the build Phases and the errors are gone but is now giving me a new one.

```
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectIpaws-fxtqgpqcnolfqvgaeikbuxwzdbcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketRocket/SocketRocket
```

The new one doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 42):

Your app must be linked against the following frameworks:

- `libicucore.dylib`
- `CFNetwork.framework`
- `Security.framework`
- `Foundation.framework`

Comment: I had this exact issues and my problem was that I wasn't linked against libicucore.dylib. Thanks!

Comment: the only library you'll likely need to add is the libicucore.dylib

Comment: OP: how did you find it out? Out of curiosity, so that we know for the future

Answer (score 2):

The file extensions changed in Xcode 7 for some reason. Add the .tbd files

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and re-build. If not try cleaning Derived Data by going into Organizer -> Projects, select your project and Delete next to the Derived Data location.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 9, add

> libicucore.tbd

in Linked Frameworks and libraries.